# How to show a tick in prompt of an item in oracle forms 12c？

Tags: properties, prompt, oracleforms, wingdings

I am working on oracle form 12c, an item is created, the prompt of the item is a tick. Here is the property of the item：

Prompt： P
Prompt font name： Wingdings 2

It displayed a tick correctly in design time, but ”P” in runtime.
How to show a tick in prompt for the item？

Many thanks

Comment: Is that font installed on the **server**?

Comment: Littlefoot, it was tested in local server

Answer (score 0):

Set_item_property(‘block.item’, Prompt_text, chr(15696828));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).